# Solve linear system in R

Tags: r, equation, equation-solving

I have a system of 3 equations :

```
g + v_1 = 8  +1/2 *v_1 +1/4 *v_2 + 1/4 *v_3
g + v_2 = 16 +1/2 *v_1 +0   *v_2 + 1/2 *v_3
g + v_3 = 7  +1/4 *v_1 +1/4 *v_2 + 1/2 *v_3
```

Setting v_3 = 0 one can obtain v_1=1.33,v_2 =7.47,v_3=0,g=9.2.

How can I solve this system in R ?

```r
A = matrix(c(1/2,1/4,1/4,
             1/2,0,1/2,
             1/4,1/4,1/2),3,byrow=TRUE);A
q = c(8,16,7)
```

Comment: This system is *singular*:  `rowSums((A-diag(3))[,c(1,3)])  == A[,2]`, therefore there are infinitely many solutions ... that makes it harder.

Comment: @BenBolker the example is from Ronald Howard's [book](https://gwern.net/doc/statistics/decision/1960-howard-dynamicprogrammingmarkovprocesses.pdf) page 46.

Comment: @Dave2e v_3 = 0 is a boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the built in `solve()` function for this task.  First a little algebra is required.
Simplifying your equations becomes:

```
 -8  = -1/2 *v_1 +1/4 *v_2 + 1/4 *v_3 - g
 -16 = +1/2 *v_1 -1   *v_2 + 1/2 *v_3 - g
 -7  = +1/4 *v_1 +1/4 *v_2 - 1/2 *v_3 - g
```

There are 4 unknowns; g, v1, v2 and v3 but only 3 equations.  An assumption is required: v3=0

```
 -8  = -1/2 *v_1 +1/4 *v_2  - g
 -16 = +1/2 *v_1 -1   *v_2 - g
 -7  = +1/4 *v_1 +1/4 *v_2  - g
```

Now your matrix is:

```
A = matrix(c(-1/2, 1/4, -1,
              1/2,  -1, -1,
              1/4, 1/4, -1), 3, byrow=TRUE)
```

the constants are:

```
B = -c(8,16,7)
```

Use the `solve()` function.

```
 solve(A, B)
 #[1] 1.333333 7.466667 9.200000
```

Comment: Nice. I had done this more automatically via `M <- cbind((A - diag(3))[,1:2], -1); solve(M, -q)` but your answer is clearer